# How to only send self-allocated framebuffer to OpenMV IDE?

Tags: python, ide, framebuffer, openmv

For a motion detection algorithm on the [OpenMV](https://openmv.io/) platform, I allocate a second framebuffer, which is being updated every frame.

Now the algorithm works, but I would like to show the result framebuffer in the OpenMV IDE. As shown in this [thread](http://forums.openmv.io/viewtopic.php?t=772), it is working with following line of code:

```
print(extra_fb.compressed_for_ide(), end="")
```

Everything works as expected, but the problem I am facing now, is, that the `extra_fb` framebuffer is shown, and then the `internal` framebuffer is shown in the IDE. So it always switches from one to the other, which results in a flickering image.

**How can I suppress the IDE from displaying the `internal` framebuffer?**

I could not find something about that in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to turn off the frame buffer connection to the IDE from the OpenMV Cam side:

```
import omv
omv.disable_fb(True)
```